# Why does my IPA file look like this when uploading/publishing to App Store?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I'm getting this error: 'This bundle is invalid. The IPA format requires a top-level directory named Payload, containing only a .app bundle and optional plugins in a Plugins directory.'

It should contain a .app bundle, and I'm wondering why it doesn't look like that.

[IPA file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWsUg.png)

Any inputs would be helpful :)

Comment: Right-click on your app file inside the Products folder in Xcode and select Show in Finder to see if it's there.

Comment: Thanks, just solved like a couple minutes ago lol

Answer (score 0):

Set mach-o type in build settings to 'executable'. Mine was previously set to static library.